# Can a weak acid react to give a stronger acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, reactivity

I was trying to understand why $\ce{AgCl}$ does not dissolve in $\ce{HNO3}$ and the reaction I could think of was something like this:

$$\ce{AgCl + HNO3->AgNO3 + HCl}$$

I could not understand why this reaction wouldn't take place. Research on similar reactions further led me to the question: "Can a weak acid react to give a stronger acid (Although I understand that in the above reaction both acids are strong)?"

Comment: See reaction of boric acid, with sugars, glycerol or generally vicinal alkohols with OH group on neighbour atoms.

Comment: Come to think of it, _not an acid at all_ can react to give a strong acid.

Answer (score 1):

Can a weak acid react to give a stronger acid? Well, yes, if you set up the right conditions. For instance, sulfuric acid (estimated first pK = -3) can be heated with $NaCl$ to boil off $HCl$ (pK = -5.9) according to Wikipedia. $HCl$ is driven from the reaction arena as a gas.

You will claim that’s a special case, with unusual conditions (the boiling off). But in the question, $AgCl$ is tightly bound and leaves the reaction arena, leaving $H^+$ and $NO_3^-$ to bounce around freely and separately. The $AgCl$ just sits there.

To put some numbers on a scale, 1 gram of $AgCl$ in water is 99.9% bound as solid (and therefore out of the reaction arena: solubility is 0.0009 g/L). Less than 0.1% is “loose” - ionized and available for reaction with other ions. On the other hand, 1 gram of nitric acid in water is 100% ionized.

The binding in a weak acid is not as tight as in the case of $AgCl$, but is not nearly as loose as in $HNO_3$. Formic acid, a fairly strong weak acid, has a pK = 3.75. One gram (0.022 mole) in a liter of water will be approximately 10% ionized (“loose”), and 90% unionized. Now the fact that formic acid is totally dissolved and seems “loose” in one sense, and is also in a mobile equilibrium, exchanging protons with water faster than you can blink, doesn’t cancel out the fact that formate ions are mostly bound up to protons. If a stronger acid were produced, the freer protons would attach to the (few) formate ions and bind them up even more. So there is no chance for formic acid to loosen up more than its pK allows - unless you can take those protons from the reaction arena. They don’t go away to a stronger acid unless you can take that whole stronger acid molecule away from the reaction arena. Formic acid is not very stable, but I propose that a mixture of concentrated formic acid (say, 90%) plus $NaCl$ and gentle heating, below the boiling point of formic acid (100.8 C), would evolve $HCl$ at first, but as sodium formate is formed, the ionization of the acid would be depressed until it is too weak to form enough hydrogens to give $HCl$ to drive off. So this case would resemble the reaction of sulfuric acid with salt, but could not be driven to completion. (Even with $H_2SO_4$, only the first proton is available; the second is too weak to drive off $HCl$ efficiently.)

Answer (score 1):

Your cited reaction proceeds, but in the reverse directions as follows:

$$\ce{HCl (aq) + AgNO3 (aq) -> AgCl (s) + HNO3 (aq)}$$

So apparently, a weak acid can react to give a 'stronger acid', albeit, in dilute form, with the creation of an insoluble precipitate.

This is relatedly evident, as one can also produce a dilute version of the acids like HI, HBr, HCl, HNO3, H2SO4, for example, from the action of Oxalic acid on the respective aqueous salts $\ce{CaI2, CaBr2, CaCl2, Ca(NO3)2}$ and finally $\ce{K2SO4}$.

In fact, it did a thread on it on another forum, with the underlying reaction given, for example, by:

$$\ce{H2C2O4 (s) + CaI2 (aq) -> Ca(C2O4)2 (s) + 2 HI (aq)}$$

which parallels the reaction cited above, but why? Because the corresponding formed oxalate salt is of very low solubility, barring a concentrated acidic medium, as is also the case of Silver chloride in dilute Nitric acid, per [Wikipedia on Silver chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_chloride), to quote:

> Solubility: soluble in NH3, conc. HCl, conc. H2SO4, alkali cyanide,...; insoluble in alcohol, dilute acids.

A side note, caution apparently distilling down, in the case of created H2SO4 by Oxalic acid (in an attempt to directly create highly concentrated H2SO4), has been observed, in the presence of formed highly concentrated sulfuric acid, to then act on the Oxalic acid. This can result in a gaseous decomposition of the Oxalic acid itself, as noted by a sudden dangerous ejection of the created concentrated H2SO4 from the vessel.